# Skype desktop app AND WEB blocked by something on my computer, working in other devices on the same network

Tags: windows, networking, skype

I did an interview over Skype which was recorded. The file ended-up having 800mb. The recording was playing fine on Skype app. I tried to download it and the file was incomplete, less than half of the actual video which is playable through Skype app.

I tried to download it through Chrome, everything was going fine until a little bit past 50%, download speed was decreasing and eventually got stuck at 0 Bps.

After this, something weird happened. The Desktop app cannot connect anymore. And the website doesn't load on any browser I have. Disabled firewall, nothing changed.

Thought it might be a problem with either my internet connection or Skype webservers. But Skype is working fine on my phone (the app) and the website at least loads (though my phone doesn't support skype web).

Still, I can't even load Skype web now to try to download again, can't try it over the desktop app. My internet connection is working fine. It is not the firewall, what else could this be? There is something blocking connections to Skype servers on my computer (Windows 10).

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

I was gonna delete this question but will leave it out here because from what I gathered it is pretty common to run in all sorts of problems when downloading Skype recordings.

It was a DNS issue, just changed the DNS server to Google's DNS and it worked.

However, I reverted the DNS back to test it again after downloading, and for some mysterious reason the same thing happened again. Connected to Skype, download started, then it stopped and Skype app and web would not connect/load anymore. Don't know whats up with that but may help someone in the future.